# Using COUNIF with with filtered rows

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-statements, formula

I am attempting to use a COUNTIF function to count the number of times a specific product fails testing in a list of many tests.

Something like:
`=COUNTIF(B1:B1000,"fail") BUT ONLY IF,(C1:C1000,"D3")`

D3 = the name of the product I am looking for.

Essentially, I want to count the number of times where a single row has:
column B=Fail
column C=product described in D3 (i.e. a filtered column)

I've tried using an SUM/AND function but it counts the number of times the product appears in column C plus all the times "fail" appears for all products in column B.

Neither allowed me to filter out all the times other products failed and only count my product of interests fails.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple criteria, use `COUNTIFS`. Additionally, when referencing a cell as a criteria, you don't need to enclose it in quotes.

```
=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$1000, "fail", $C$1:$C$1000, $D$3)
```